# How to specify only one root (if multiple root exist in the data) while processing hierarchical data using pregel in spark graphx

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

Please follow this example :
[Processing Hierarchical Data Using Spark GraphX Pregel API](https://dzone.com/articles/processing-hierarchical-data-using-spark-graphx-pr)

There is only one root in the sample data: EMP001 i.e. Bob Baker. 
Let's assume if we add another root in the data like: ("EMP000", "Chris", "Jonas", "CEO", null.asInstanceOf[String]) and one guy reporting to him: ("EMP044", "Harry", "Sharma", "CTO", "EMP000")

Now if we follow the code given in the article, will get all the hierarchies starting with EMP001 Bob Baker and EMP000 Chris Jonas as well. 
How do I restrict the traversal to only those nodes whose root is EMP001 i.e. Bob Baker?

Comment: Can you please specify the use case that you are trying to address?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to find out the all the sub-parts of a particular part in Bill Of Material(BOM). Oracle supports hierarchical query where you have a clause "start with " which help you to specify the root for which you want the traversal. Now, if you can't specify the root, then for all finished part(root), the query will run and if millions of root exist, the query will die. So, the same way, I am looking for a solution in spark graphx to specify the root.